# Images are not loading on netlify and links aren't working

Tags: html, netlify

```css
html{
  background-color:#abb2bc;
}

body{
  margin:0;

}
h1 {
  margin:0;
  background-color: #363b42;
}
img{
  width:250px;
}

.navbar{
  text-align:center;
}

.blogpost{
  background-color:white;
  padding:5%;
  margin:3%

}

#blogheader{
  margin-top:15px;
}

.blogimage{
  margin-top:25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>GamingCoachBlog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
      <div class="navbar">
        <h1>GamingCoach</h1>
      </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="blogpost">
      <h2 id="blogheader">Recent Blog Posts</h2>
      <a  href="/Users/david/Desktop/Blog/Articles/Ten Fortnite Tips For Season 8/index.html"><img class="blogimage" src="/Users/david/Desktop/Blog/Images/How to get more wins in Fortnite.png" alt="How to get more wins in Fortnite"></a>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

I connected my github repository to my netlify website and it loads fine. In my github repo it has an images folder but my images will not load.
I also have a link set to the images that has another html file linked to it but whenever i click on it it says page not found. Please explain why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the path that you want to link at or it won't know where do you want to point at.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>GamingCoachBlog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
      <div class="navbar">
        <h1>GamingCoach</h1>
      </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="blogpost">
      <h2 id="blogheader">Recent Blog Posts</h2>
      <a  href="C:/Users/david/Desktop/Blog/Articles/Ten Fortnite Tips For Season 8/index.html"><img class="blogimage" src="C:/Users/david/Desktop/Blog/Images/How to get more wins in Fortnite.png" alt="How to get more wins in Fortnite"></a>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by specifying the path that i want to link. I put the C: before the /Users but now when i load the website on my local server it doesn't load there now either.

Comment: this seems to be a duplicate of this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029111/photos-wont-load-and-links-are-dead - which has a good and correct answer