# Photos won't load and links are dead

Tags: html, css, hosting, netlify

So I hosted my website on netlify with my github repo. All of my photos and files used in the site are there but they will not load. Only my index.html and style.css that is outside of all of the folders will load. I have a link to my github repo. [Github Repo](https://github.com/CarmtieStars/gamingcoach)

```css
html{
  background-color:#abb2bc;
}

body{
  margin:0;

}
h1 {
  margin:0;
  background-color: #363b42;
}
img{
  width:250px;
}

.navbar{
  text-align:center;
}

.blogpost{
  background-color:white;
  padding:5%;
  margin:3%

}

#blogheader{
  margin-top:15px;
}

.blogimage{
  margin-top:25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>GamingCoachBlog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
      <div class="navbar">
        <h1>GamingCoach</h1>
      </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="blogpost">
      <h2 id="blogheader">Recent Blog Posts</h2>
      <a href="/Users/david/Desktop/Blog/Articles/Ten Fortnite Tips For Season 8/index.html"><img class="blogimage" src="C:/Users/david/Desktop/Blog/Images/How to get more wins in Fortnite.png" alt="How to get more wins in Fortnite"></a>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A few things you are trying to load images from your local C drive change the image src to be relative to your project directory. ie ./Images/myImg.png
Also you can NOT have spaces in image names on the web, rename all your images without spaces

Comment: Perhaps bc your href links are completely wrong... You are loading the images from your local C drive...

Comment: Change the `src` `C:/Users/david/Desktop/Blog/Images/How to get more wins in Fortnite.png` of your image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'C://' refrences, or local refrences, do not work online. Aside from this, using spaces in your webpage name and file name is not recommended, as some browsers may not support spaces or will convert them to the web standard, a '+', or the unicode standard for space (U+0020) so that more actions can be performed on them.

FIX:

> Swap
>   src="C:/Users/david/Desktop/Blog/Images/How to get more wins in Fortnite.png"
>   with
>   src="Images/How to get more wins in Fortnite.png"

to fix your problem and render the photo correctly, assuming your browser doesn't object to the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem my photos were saved in assets wasn't displaying in the netlify page and also while refreshing the page it showed like page not found . For these 2 problems I used the following steps.

**Step 1:**

Use **_redirects** file inside Public folder having the following code `/* /index.html 200` which helps to redirect to your page. After adding that file use **npm run build** so that will be updated in **build** folder.

**Step 2:**

To show the images I've created a folder inside build folder named admin and inside that folder I've pasted the folder named static which was available inside build folder.

Hope this might be helpful in some cases!